# Unable to detect a unicode in R

Tags: r, string, nlp, text-mining

In R we are trying to detect check boxes and checked boxes. The complete PDF is read through pdftools package and stored in the form of dataframe. [image]

The check boxes are stored in the form of "U+F0A8" character (removed < & > sign enclosing the character "U+F0A8"as it's not visible with < & > signs ) While performing string detect or gref functions or just printing it these characters are not detected or printed. Kindly help. I have attached the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some data to your question. What is your desired output?

Comment: we'd need to see the source PDF and code for what you're doing to read it in.

Comment: Sorry the PDF files are confidential...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fixed` so it compares only bytes:

```
str_detect(String(splitted_query_text_AA[70,1]), fixed("<U+F0FE>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.

> String(splitted_query_text_AA[77,1])
>                             (2)               Plan Year
>
> stri_enc_isutf16be(splitted_query_text_AA[77,1])
>   [1] TRUE
>
> stri_escape_unicode(splitted_query_text_AA[77,1])
>   [1] "                          (2)       \uf0fe        Plan Year"
>
> str_detect(stri_escape_unicode(splitted_query_text_AA[77,1]), "uf0fe")
>   [1] TRUE

Thank you